# TCAM utilization on Nexus 9396 switches

Tags: cisco, firewall, acl, cisco-nexus

I have Cisco Nexus 9396 switch which is running L3 mode and i have configured bunch of IPv4 access-list in Ingress for firewalling to block certain traffic.

I am reading about TCAM and wanted to understand what i should look into following output?

Does `Used` column number represent to number of ACL rules?

```
# show hardware access-list resource utilization

slot  1
=======



INSTANCE 0x0
-------------


         ACL Hardware Resource Utilization (Mod 1)
         ----------------------------------------------------------
                                        Used    Free    Percent
                                                        Utilization
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ingress IPv4 PACL                       3       509     0.59
Ingress IPv4 Port QoS                   4       252     1.56
Ingress IPv4 VACL                       2       510     0.39
Ingress IPv4 RACL                       226     286     44.14
Egress IPv4 VACL                        3       509     0.59
Egress IPv4 RACL                        3       253     1.17
SUP COPP                                205     51      80.08
SUP COPP Reason Code TCAM               6       122     4.69
Redirect                                2       510     0.39
SPAN                                    21      235     8.20
VPC Convergence                         1       255     0.39

LOU                                     2       22      8.33
Both LOU Operands                       2
Single LOU Operands                     0
LOU L4 src port:                        1
LOU L4 dst port:                        1
LOU L3 packet len:                      0
LOU IP tos:                             0
LOU IP dscp:                            0
LOU ip precedence:                      0
LOU ip TTL:                             0
TCP Flags                               0       16      0.00

Protocol CAM                            2       244     0.81
Mac Etype/Proto CAM                     0       14      0.00

L4 op labels, Tcam 0                    0       1023    0.00
L4 op labels, Tcam 2                    1       62      1.58
L4 op labels, Tcam 6                    0       2047    0.00

Ingress Dest info table                 0       512     0.00
Egress Dest info table                  0       512     0.00
```